# MFC how to resize CStatic to a small size

Tags: c++, mfc

I have the following issue with the CStatic control:

When I call function `SetIcon`:

```
    m_CStatic.SetIcon(AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_ICON1));
```

It loads an icon that have a size 14x14 pixels, but the actual size of the control becomes 21x20 and I can not to modify it.

I tried to call:

```
    m_CStatic.SetWindowPos(NULL,0 , 0, 14, 14, SWP_NOMOVE);
```

But it only cuts a size without resizing of the icon. As result I have a part of zoomed image.

Is there any way to set a size of an icon to load?

**EDIT**

An actual size of the `IDI_ICON1` is **14x14** pixels.

Also the size of the `CStatic` control is **21x20** and I can not change it with the designer.

When I load an icon it is stretched. I have no idea why.

Comment: What size is the actual icon resource in `IDI_ICON1`? Does it contain more than one icon size? When you say that "the actual size of the control becomes 21x21", do you mean that the 14x14 pixel icon is stretched to 21x21 pixels? Or does the control just have padding added around its borders? Anyway, note that a static control will not resize its icon when you change the size. It will not zoom or shrink, it will just clip. You have to do the image manipulation yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An actual size of the `IDI_ICON1` is 14x14 pixels.
>
> Also the size of the `CStatic` control is 21x20 and I can not change it with the designer.

If you're looking at the size of the control in the designer, you're not comparing apples to apples here. The designer is reporting the size of controls in **DLUs** (dialog box units), **not pixels**.

There is not necessarily a 1-to-1 mapping between DLUs and pixels. In fact, the whole point of a DLU is that it is pixel-independent. The actual number of pixels represented by a single DLU will change depending on the fonts and DPI of the computer you're running the application on.

So the behavior you're seeing makes perfect sense to me.

If you don't believe this DLUs vs. pixels silliness, then try running the application under the debugger and using Spy++ to investigate the actual size (in pixels) of the static control. I'll bet it's 14x14.

And no, you cannot resize a static control in the designer if you have it set to display an icon. The control is automatically sized to accommodate the icon it is displaying. That's also by design. I can't imagine why you'd want to; your whole point seems to be that you don't want the icon to be clipped.

But like I said in a comment, static controls do not automatically scale their icons. You need to write code to do the icon scaling yourself (probably by calling the [`DrawIconEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648065.aspx)). Forcing the static control to resize itself will just crop the icon or add a border around it. Adding the `SS_CENTERIMAGE` style, as [duDE suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15321713/366904) will alter this behavior so that the icon is aligned to the center of the static control, subtly changing how the cropping happens. But it will still get cropped to fit the static control's size.

Do be careful, though. The whole point of my line of questioning in the comments regarding the icon actually in `IDI_ICON1` is that the `LoadIcon` function has some important limitations. Namely, it is only designed to load icons with the `SM_CXICON` and `SM_CYICON` sizes (on most systems, that will be 32x32). It does work as expected when you only have one icon defined in the icon resource, but it will fall apart otherwise. That could have been the explanation for the stretching. Instead, it's recommended that you use the [`LoadImage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045.aspx). The code is rather more verbose, but it's a more powerful function:

```
HICON hIcon = static_cast<HICON>(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),
                                 MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1),
                                 IMAGE_ICON,
                                 14,   /* width (x dimension) */
                                 14,   /* height (y dimension) */
                                 LR_DEFAULTCOLOR));
// (make sure to call DestroyIcon() on hIcon when you're done with it!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CStatic m_CStatic;

// Create a child icon static control
m_CStatic.Create(_T("my static"), 
   WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|SS_ICON|SS_CENTERIMAGE, CRect(0 , 0, 14, 14), pParentWnd);

// Set the icon
m_CStatic.SetIcon(::LoadIcon(IDI_ICON1));
```

The point is SS_CENTERIMAGE:

A bitmap is centered in the static control that contains it. 
The control is not resized, so that **a bitmap** too large for the control **will be clipped**.

Comment: When I used `SS_CENTERIMAGE` for an initial control it cropped an icon. But I still don't understand why it resizes an icon on load.